# Asynchrony on ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would want to increase the performance of my web application for future scalability issues,

One scenario that i think of is that, if i need a list that needs to be filtered from the database.

Here is the rough draft that i made:

```
public IEnumerable<test> getL(IEnumerable<test> filter)
{
        //do some filtering from the list then return it
        return filter;
}



public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
      context con = new context();       
      //do more stuff of stuff
      IEnumerable<test> get = await Task.Run(() => { return getL(con.dep.ToList()); });   
      return View(get);
}
```

I am kinda new with C#'s asynchrony so i am kinda wondering if i am doing this correct. Did i start the asynchronous call properly?

Comment: This is probably more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/? But, the code looks to work for me. The request to `Index` will be awaited while the db task completes. Depending on your database access method you may be able to await the call to the database instead. E.g. if you are using Dapper there are async methods.

Comment: So when it reaches the line of await, it will wait until the task is finished?

Comment: It will actually serve another web request until the task is complete, hence the asynchronous part. In a non-async world, the thread will be occupied until the entire `Index` method is complete, so this will potentially improve performance.

Comment: ahhh so while waiting, it will serve another thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ASP.NET, you should avoid `Task.Run`. This is because `Task.Run` will free up the current thread *by using another thread*. So you incur the penalty of an additional context switch for no reason. This code will *decrease* scalability and performance, not increase it.

Instead, use `await` for I/O-based tasks. For example, getting the data from the database:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  context con = new context();       
  var list = await con.dep.ToListAsync();
  IEnumerable<test> get = getL(list);
  return View(get);
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you. I am kinda new so, can you give me more examples of I/O based task?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta: Reading or writing files, HTTP requests, and database calls are the most common.